# How to pass values from Java to Javascript insiede an Android WebView

Tags: javascript, android, android-webview

I'm building an Android application where i have to use javascript to show a map.
I'm using a WebView that loads an HTML file stored in the assets folder.

```
    wv=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView1);
    wvs=wv.getSettings();
    wv.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
    wvs.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    wv.addJavascriptInterface(new WebAppInterface(this), "Android");
    wv.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/android_index.html");
```

In this file, the code dislpays a map using a JavaScript method.
I have to center the map (and add a pin) to the current device position.
The methods that do these things work fine and the i get the current device position correctly.
So, i have to pass the coordinates to the JavaScript method called in the HTML file.

Here the script line where i should use the coordinates:

```
jQuery(function ($) {
        var map;
        ...
        map.setCenter(/*here latitude*/,/*here longtitude*/);
        ..
});
```

How can i pass from Java to JavaScript the values i get from the device?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9749900/webview-addjavascriptinterface-function-with-parameters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Android 4.3 and below, and on Android 4.4+ with `android:targetSdkVersion` set to 18 or lower, call `loadUrl()` on the `WebView`, with a `javascript:` URL, the same way you set up a bookmarklet on a desktop OS.

On Android 4.4+ with `android:targetSdkVersion` set to 19 or higher, use the new `evaluateJavaScript()` method on `WebView`.